# Extracting data from html and generating a CSV

Tags: html, web-scraping

I have a large HTML file that contains about 400 customer reviews. Is there a tool that I can use to scrap the file and grab specific data out of it and put them in a CSV file? The goal is to transfer these reviews from an old website into a new website for the same company.

The HTML that contains each review looks like this (the file has 400 of these blocks):

```
  <section class="reviews-16465185">
    <div class="internal-review">
      <div class="">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="reviewer"><span>Joe K.</span></div>
          <div class="internal-rating">
            <div class="top" style="width: 100%">
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i
              ><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i
              ><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
              <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i
              ><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i
              ><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="review-rating">
            <meta content="1" />
            <meta content="5.0" />
            <meta content="5" />
          </div>
          <div class="review-date">
            <meta content="2022-01-05" />Submitted 01/05/22
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <div class="type-full">
            <span
              >Review goes here Review Goes Here Review Goes Here</span
            >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

The data I need to get is the reviewer's name, rating, date, and review.

I prefer a tool either in js, node js, php, or python.

Comment: One thing is unclear: what's the "rating" in your sample html: `1`,`5`, or `5.0`?

Comment: @JackFleeting rating is 5.0. The other two is just the scale which means the ratings can be from 1 to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using python (although it can be also done with both js and php) and utilizing xpath, you can try the following:

```
import lxml.html as lh
reviews = """your html above"""

doc = lh.fromstring(reviews)
sections = doc.xpath('//section')
for section in sections:
    reviewer = section.xpath('.//div[@class="reviewer"]/span/text()')[0]
    date = section.xpath('.//div[@class="review-date"]/meta/@content')[0]
    review = section.xpath('.//div[@class="type-full"]/span/text()')[0]
    rating = section.xpath('.//div[@class="review-rating"]//meta/@content')[1]

    print(f"{date}, {reviewer}, {review}, {rating}")
```

The output should be

```
2022-01-05, Joe K., Review goes here Review Goes Here Review Goes Here, 5.0
```